# How do you place elements on a new row, same column with css-grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

My content is overlapping. I understand it is because I put the same `col-start`, but how do I get the content divs to go grow and go down the middle of my css-grid?  Should I be using flexbox with the grid here?  (no Bootstrap please)

Here is what it looks like now:

```css
.mygrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, [col-start] 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.content {
  grid-column: col-start 4 / span 7;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div class="content">test1</div>
  <div class="content">test2</div>
  <div class="content">test3</div>
  <div class="content">test41</div>
  <div class="content">test51</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gzmGbQ

I wanted a the content divs to go down the rows each new div, but it needs to start at that column and span that many columns.

Comment: what is th desired output

Comment: @TemaniAfif I added that.

Comment: You are creating the grid and assigning all of the elements to the same location in the grid. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: @Daniel I mentioned that in the question.  I'm asking the correct way to do it because I don't know how.

Comment: You may need to draw a picture of what you want the layout to look. You mention bootstrap, are you trying to re-create the column / row layout classes?

Comment: @Daniel I want to use css-grid, native.  I don't want to use Bootstrap.

Comment: I suggest removing the grid-row property if that is the result you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specifically told all items to occupy the same row (`grid-row: 1 / 3`). Why not remove that rule?

```css
.mygrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, [col-start] 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.content {
  grid-column: col-start 4 / span 7;
  /* grid-row: 1 / 3; */
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div class="content">test1</div>
  <div class="content">test2</div>
  <div class="content">test3</div>
  <div class="content">test41</div>
  <div class="content">test51</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But what if I wanted the rows to start at row 1 or 3 or x, instead of the top?

Comment: @Michael_B You have created a circular reference ! (Because the other question links to this one)