# Selecting a starting column and row for a series of grid items

Tags: css, css-grid

If I have this below, all the data will overlap [because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108173/how-do-you-place-elements-on-a-new-row-same-column-with-css-grid/50108511?noredirect=1#comment87253060_50108511) I told it to go to the same column *and* row.  How can I make it start at the column and row I want and it "grow"?

If I remove the row, it goes down the page as expected.  But what if I wanted it to start at Row 1/3, 5/12, etc.?  Can you do that?

```css
.mygrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, [col-start] 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.content {
  grid-column: col-start 4 / span 7;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div class="content">test1</div>
  <div class="content">test2</div>
  <div class="content">test3</div>
  <div class="content">test41</div>
  <div class="content">test51</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a pure CSS Grid solution for such behavior, but there is still a clean and simple CSS solution.

**Use a pseudo-element.**

In grid layout (like in flex layout), pseudo-elements on the container are considered items. Therefore, insert a pseudo that will span across empty rows.

In the example below, your content items start on row 6. No need to alter the column rule.

```css
.mygrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, [col-start] 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.content {
  grid-column: col-start 4 / span 7;
  /* grid-row: 1 / 3; */
}

.mygrid::before {
  content: "";
  grid-row: 1 / span 5;
  grid-column: col-start 4 / span 7;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div class="content">test1</div>
  <div class="content">test2</div>
  <div class="content">test3</div>
  <div class="content">test41</div>
  <div class="content">test51</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set this style only on the first *content*

```css
.mygrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, [col-start] 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  grid-auto-rows: 20px;
}

.content {
  grid-column: col-start 4 / span 7;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.content:first-child {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div class="content">test1</div>
  <div class="content">test2</div>
  <div class="content">test3</div>
  <div class="content">test41</div>
  <div class="content">test51</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would just add `align-self: flex-end` to bring the content together. https://jsfiddle.net/u3h3pwt5/

Comment: @Michael_B Suddenly I realized that probably the OP wants all the elements to have *span 2*. And then , it looks good without need for align-self.  But, just trying to guess OP idea here

Comment: My impression was that the content items were to be "indented" vertically (with empty rows), as they already are horizontally (with empty columns).

Comment: @Michael_B Yes, I understood your idea, and I was going to edit my answer, but then I had the other one. Only the OP knows for sure :-)